# How do I invoke a system command and capture its output?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to invoke a system command, like `ls` or `fuser` in Rust? How about capturing its output?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

[`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) allows for that.

There are multiple ways to spawn a child process and execute an arbitrary command on the machine:

- [`spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) — runs the program and returns a value with details
- [`output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) — runs the program and returns the output
- [`status`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) — runs the program and returns the exit code

One simple example from the docs:

```
use std::process::Command;

Command::new("ls")
        .arg("-l")
        .arg("-a")
        .spawn()
        .expect("ls command failed to start");
```

Comment: What if i need to get real-time output. I think `output` function returns Vec after completion of process. So, in case if we run something like `Command("ping google.com")`. Is this possible to get this commands output as it will not finish but I want to print its logs. Please suggest.

Comment: @GrvTyagi: `spawn`, mentioned in this answer, returns a [`Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) result with standard I/O streams.

Comment: Building off of this excellent answer, I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597789/11639533) helpful for understanding how to interact with stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 104):

a very clear example from the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html):

```
use std::process::Command;
let output = Command::new("/bin/cat")
                     .arg("file.txt")
                     .output()
                     .expect("failed to execute process");

println!("status: {}", output.status);
println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));

assert!(output.status.success());
```

Answer (score 12):

It is indeed possible! The relevant module is [`std::run`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/run/index.html).

```
let mut options = std::run::ProcessOptions::new();
let process = std::run::Process::new("ls", &[your, arguments], options);
```

`ProcessOptions`’ standard file descriptors [default to `None`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/run/struct.ProcessOptions.html) (create a new pipe), so you can just use [`process.output()`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/run/struct.Process.html#method.output) (for example) to read from its output.

If you want to run the command and get all its output after it’s done, [there’s `wait_with_output` for that](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/process/struct.Process.html#method.wait_with_output).

`Process::new`, as of yesterday, returns an `Option<Process>` instead of a `Process`, by the way.

Comment: It's `std::process` now as of rustc 1.19.0.

Answer (score 2):

`Command` builds and configures a child process. When you create a new instance of Command and specify the command you want to execute, any arguments, environment variables, and other settings, you are defining the configuration for a child process.

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

let system_command = "echo";
let argument = "Hello World";

let echo_hello: std::process::Output = Command::new(system_command)
                        .arg(argument)
                        //.current_dir(TEST_PATH)
                        // Stdio::piped() creates pipes to capture stdout and stderr of a child process which is created by Command. 
                        // we are telling the Command to create a pipe to capture the standard output (stdout) of the child process.
                        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                        // creating a pipe to capture the standard error (stderr) of the child process.
                        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
                        // output() executes the child process synchronously and captures its output. 
                        //It returns a std::process::Output struct containing information about the process's exit status, stdout, and stderr.
                        .output()
                        .expect("Failed to echo");
```

you could use `spawn()` instead of `output()` to execute the child process asynchronously. Using `spawn()` will allow the child process to run independently of the parent process. `spawn()` returns

```
std::process::Child
```

If you need to terminate the child process prematurely for some reason, you can call the `kill()` method on the `std::process::Child`  handle. On the other hand, once the `output()` method is called, the child process runs to completion, and there is no direct mechanism provided by `output()` to terminate the process prematurely.