# Running an external process in Rust

Tags: rust

I saw this question [In Rust, how do I invoke a system command and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-in-a-rust-program) but it seems something has changed. So how do I run an external process in Rust now?

Comment: [talles's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25574952/234590) on that question is still valid, I believe. `std::run` has been removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I invoke a system command in a Rust program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-in-a-rust-program)

Comment: I believe std::run or core::run was being rewritten, rather than removed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `std::io::process::Command`?

You could try something like.

```
let process = match std::io::process::Command::new("ls")
                       .args(&["-l", "/home/hduser"])
                       .spawn() {
        Ok(process) => process,
        Err(err)    => panic!("Running process error: {}", err),
};

let output = match process.wait_with_output() {
        Ok(output)  => output,
        Err(err)    => panic!("Retrieving output error: {}", err),
};

let stdout = match std::string::String::from_utf8(output.output) {
        Ok(stdout)  => stdout,
        Err(err)    => panic!("Translating output error: {}", err),
};

print!("{}", stdout);
```

You don't have to spawn the process, but it is what Rust is great at, so why not. `Command::new` returns a `Option`, `wait_with_output()` returns an `IoResult`, and `from_utf8` returns a `Result`, so I used a match expression to unwrap the results, but you could just as easily use `.ok().expect("Some descriptive text for error")` instead of the match expressions.

Example without spawn and match expressions:

```
let process = std::io::process::Command::new("pwd")
                              .output()
                              .ok()
                              .expect("Failed to execute");
let out = std::string::String::from_utf8(process.output)
                              .ok()
                              .expect("Failed to read"));
println!("{}", out);
```

Comment: `.ok().expect("...")` is considered an anti-pattern in today's Rust - one can use `expect("...")` directly on the `Result`. The benefit is that `Result::expect` produces an error message that includes the cause of the error (much like in the code sample with the explicit `match`), which `Option::expect` cannot do because the error part of the result was lost during the conversion of `Result` to `Option`.

Comment: In modern rust this is `std::process::Command`