Rust: run docker exec command in external terminal/shell(as interactive window)
I have this piece of code part of my desktop app that I am building using Rust+Tauri(A docker GUI client). I want to allow the user to click on the button and it should spwan a terminal app that basically runs the exec command.
The Problem:
I have figured out how to do it for my system(running Linux/Pop!os) but how do I make it work on all the various linux distros (for now, cross-os support will be later). I know I have "gnome-terminal" app that I can hardcoded it & it is working.
let mut terminal_app: String = String::from("gnome-terminal"); // How do I get this dynamically?

let docker_command = format!("docker exec -it {} sh", container_name);

let mut command = std::process::Command::new(terminal_app);
let args = ["--", "bash", "-c", &docker_command];;

command.args(&args);
match command.spawn() {
    Ok(_) => Ok("Exec command executed".to_string()),
    Err(err) => Err(format!("Cannot run exec command: {}", err.to_string())),
}

I will be grateful for your help...

Do you want to spawn an interactive window ? Or do you just want to run the process (and possibly capture its output) ? In the latter case, I'd go for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478009/running-an-external-process-in-rust

I want to run an interactive window.

When using Linux, most modern desktops will support xdg-open. If you open a specific shell or file with this command, it will interface with the user preferences to open their preferred terminal emulator. Of course, MacOS and Windows have completely different methods of opening applications.

(You shouldn't routinely need docker exec: how would you get an interactive shell inside your non-container Rust application, and why is it different in a container?  The format! call introduces a significant shell-injection security bug and I'd also fix that.)

@DavidMaze thanks for pointing out the security issue but this is going to be a desktop app it is pretty much under my control as what gets passed to the format!. Do you still think It applies?

I guess if the user can run docker exec then they can already take over the entire system, but it's still not a great practice.

@DavidMaze the user does have control to docker exec as whole. User will click on a button that will open a terminal window inside the docker container using docker exec

In you app settings ask for the name of the terminal and command line to execute and external command, probably using placeholders.
There's also xdg-terminal-exec but not commonly installed.
Finally, you can also rely on environment vars like TERMINAL or something more specific for. your app.
