# In Rust how do I run an executeable interactively so I can input and recieve output multiple times all as one process?

Tags: linux, rust, input, process

My end goal is to make a website that allows a user to input and receive output from an executable using web sockets. For example a command line interface chess program. I want to execute other binaries from inside my web server code and in simplest case give 2 total inputs and receive the first output before the second input. My problem is that you seemingly cannot write to stdin more than once for a single process.

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    for i in 0..2 {
        print!("Output: ");
        let _ = io::stdout().flush();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer)?;
        println!("{}", buffer.trim().chars().rev().collect::<String>());
        buffer.clear();
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

```
use std::io::{self, Write, Read};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    execute("reversed/target/debug/reversed");
}

fn read_line(buffer: &mut String) {
    io::stdin().read_line(buffer).expect("Faild to read stdin");
}
fn execute(program: &str) {
    let mut child = Command::new(program)
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to spawn child process");

    
    _ = std::thread::spawn(move || {

        let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().expect("Failed to open stdin");
        stdin.write_all("Hello, ".as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to stdin");
        drop(stdin);

// trying to write to stdin more than once panics
        
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        let mut stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("Failed to take stdout");
        _ =  stdout.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
        drop(stdout);
        println!("{}", buffer);

// the program prints
// Output: ,olleH
// Output: 

        let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().expect("Failed to open stdin");
        // thread 'main' panicked at 'failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)' 
        stdin.write_all(" world!".as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to stdin");
        drop(stdin);

    }).join();
}
```

Comment: You can't `.take()` stdin more than once, but you can most certainly write more to the `stdin` instance you took.

Comment: If you don't drop stdin it hangs and never outputs anything. If you do drop it, it outputs the rest of the program as if you input empty strings.

Comment: `"Hello, "` isn't a full line so `.read_line()` would be blocking waiting for input until a newline character (or you close stdin by dropping it).

Comment: Adding a newline to make it `Hello, ` and not calling `drop(stdin)` made the program hang and never finished when I try to `stdout.read_to_string()`. The following post is how I learned of this "indefinite blocking". [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218599/write-to-child-process-stdin-in-rust)

Comment: `read_to_string` will read the *entire* thing so it will wait until the pipe closes (which yours won't). Use something like `read_line` to only read until a newline character is printed (like `println!` does).

Comment: `Command.spawn()` returns a `Child`. Child has field `stdin` of type `ChildStdin` which does not implement `BufRead` which is required for `read_line()`. I can try 'read' but I will have to make a `[u8]` buffer. I'll try this when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Wrap it in a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) (on `stdout` not `stdin`).