# How to pipe data into a child process?

Tags: rust

I am trying to run a script in a child process and am trying to avoid writing the script to the disk and running it from that location.

I am trying to replicate this:

```
echo "console.log(42)" | node

> 42
```

I tried this but it doesn't print anything and the child never exits

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut command = Command::new("node");

  command.stderr(Stdio::inherit());
  command.stdout(Stdio::inherit());
  command.stdin(Stdio::piped());
  
  let mut child = command.spawn().unwrap();

  let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();

  stdin.write("console.log(42)".as_bytes()).unwrap();

  child.wait().unwrap();
}
```

Also does this work on Windows or is this a UNIX only concept?

EDIT:

I want to keep stdin open so I can send messages to/from the process after I have initialized the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write to child process' stdin in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218599/write-to-child-process-stdin-in-rust)

Comment: Not quite, I think I just don't understand the mechanics of executing a script from a piped value. I see that you have to close stdin for node to decide to evaluate the input - I don't think I can send an input then continue to listen on stdin after it has evaluated

Comment: You'll likely need to find a different way to communicate in your desired way with node. The issue is that programs usually blockingly read from stdin until stdin has been closed. So in the case of node, it's waiting until stdin is closed to know that no more data is coming. Dropping stdin causes it to be closed.

Comment: Are you intending to use `node` like a REPL (or at least in a request-response fashion)? Assuming this is nodejs, you may need to pass [`--interactive`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#-i---interactive) so that it behaves like one. But then you'll also need to send your "commands" as node expects (likely ending them with a newline or maybe a semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve wont't work this way. You can easily test this by executing `cat /dev/stdin | node`.
You will find out that the `node` process will not execute any of your statements until you terminate `stdin` (e.g. using Ctrl-D).

This tells us that the node process will read the entire `stdin` into a buffer before executing anything.

You could use the following javascript code (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node) question) to work around that:

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var lingeringLine = "";

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    lines = chunk.split("\n");

    lines[0] = lingeringLine + lines[0];
    lingeringLine = lines.pop();

    lines.forEach(line => eval(line));
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    eval(lingeringLine);
});
```

If you pass this code to your node process as a file(or named pipe),
you can then send it commands on `stdin` that it will execute.

Alternatively, you might be able to use `node --interactive` if you don't care about the output. I would refrain from parsing the output of this, as it is probably not standardized, as is intended to be consumed by humans.

Both of these approaches would work on windows aswell.

---

I feel obligated to point out that this is most likely not a good idea (depending on your usecase).
Other approaches like using formatted messages (e.g. json) to communicate with your node process or even using a [rust based js interpreter](https://github.com/boa-dev/boa) seem much safer and more robust than `eval`ing from stdin.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great resource. I have decided to just write my JS code to the disk and have child processes execute it from there. I have looked at embedding Deno - however I need support for node-isms as I expect consumers to use Node dependencies. I benchmarked the latency of stdio vs embedding Deno and it's about 10-20x slower (0.001ms stdio vs 0.00006ms embedded for a return trip) - but that's okay for now (maybe I'll include a "fast-js" mode for plugins that don't need Node.js support).