# How to use `std::io::Command`

Tags: rust

I am trying to execute the following code in Rust:

```
use std::io::Command;

fn main() {
    let the_output = Command::new("ruby").arg(["-e", "puts 'raja'", "x"]).output()
}
```

But it throws this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::io::Command`
 --> src\main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use std::io::Command;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Command` in `io`
```

Can someone guide me how to import this `use std::io::Command;` into my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `std::io::Command`. You were probably thinking of [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html).

Comment: Ah! Okay, thanks. Hi actually My requirement is, I wanted to run a command via `Command::new` For an example, typing `dir` in the command prompt will list out all the directories. How can I execute that command via this? If I type in my command prompt `ruby -e "puts 'raja'"` it would print `raja`, Now I wanted to execute the same line through `Command.new` and when I execute that line it has to print 'raja', how do I that?

Comment: For how to use `std::process::Command`, I recommend reading the documentation I linked. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574952/4639273) may also be enlightening. To print whatever that command sent to `stdout` and `stderr`, you can use the `stdout` and `stderr` fields on `the_output`. Just note that this data is kept as a `Vec<u8>`, so you'll have to convert it using something like `String::from_utf8`. If you're still confused, try asking a new question.