# How do I execute a command in a subshell in Rust?

Tags: rust, command, subshell

In Python, I could do `os.system("pip install bs4")`. Is there any equivalent in Rust? I've seen `std::process::Command`, but this seems to fail each time:

```
use std::process::Command;
Command::new("pip")
    .arg("install")
    .arg("bs4")
    .spawn()
    .expect("pip failed");
```

Is there any way to have the code execute a real shell and have them run in the terminal?

Comment: `Command::new("your-shell-name").args(&["whatever", "you", "need")`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the failure you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Pip requires root permissions so be sure to run your binary with sufficient privileges.

The following worked for me:

```
use std::process::Command;
Command::new("pip")
    .args(&["install", "bs4"])
    .spawn()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```

Use this to analyze the failure:

```
use std::process::Command;
let output = Command::new("pip")
    .args(&["install", "bs4"])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");

println!("status: {}", output.status);
println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));
```

Example was derived from here:

[How do I invoke a system command in Rust and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-in-rust-and-capture-its-output)

Comment: You should never use pip as root. Setup a venv or use `pip install --user`