# How to execute a command in a shell running as a child process?

Tags: rust

From the answer to [How do I invoke a system command in Rust and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574952/155423), I can execute a command which itself spawns a shell to execute commands.

```
use std::process::Command;

Command::new("sh")
    .spawn()
    .expect("sh command failed to start");
```

Is it possible to execute commands from Rust in this newly gained shell?

Comment: Shells just take commands as stdin and generates output on stdout. So in theory all you need to do is capture stdin/stdout and interact with those (write to stdin and read from stdout). It's generally a pain in the ass because of blocking & buffering & friends though, which is why tools like expect/pexpect exist to take care of all the fiddly bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let mut child = Command::new("sh").stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()?;

child.stdin
    .as_mut()
    .ok_or("Child process stdin has not been captured!")?
    .write_all(b"something...")?;

let output = child.wait_with_output()?;
```

Source: [External Command](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/os/external.html) in [*The Rust Cookbook*](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/intro.html).

Comment: Not really portable.