# How to execute chained commands in a shell running as a child process?

Tags: rust

Following the question at [How to execute a command in a shell running as a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63807700/155423), I want to execute multiple commands.

```
let mut child = Command::new("sh").stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()?;

child.stdin
    .as_mut()
    .ok_or("Child process stdin has not been captured!")?
    .write_all(b"something...")?;

let output = child.wait_with_output()?;
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
.write_all(b"something...")?
.write_all(b"something...")?;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.write_all(b"something \n something2")?` do the trick? This has nothing do with rust, just sh.

Comment: It worked @chpio, can you write it in answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem in *Rust*, but *sh*. In *sh* you need to separate commands by newlines (`"\n"`):

```rust
//...
.write_all(b"command1\ncommand2")?;
//...
```

this should work too:

```rust
//...
let child_stdin = child.stdin
    .as_mut()
    .ok_or("Child process stdin has not been captured!")?;

child_stdin.write_all(b"command1\n")?;
child_stdin.write_all(b"command2\n")?;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining method calls works for methods that, by convention, return `self` or `&mut self`. There is no guarantee that *all* methods do that, some simply have more useful return values. For example, `write_all()` returns `Result<(), io::Error>`, declaring that it has no useful value other than showing whether the writing succeeded or failed.

To call such a method twice, you need to save your value into a local variable:

```
let child_stdin = child
    .stdin
    .as_mut()
    .ok_or("Child process stdin has not been captured!")?;
child_stdin.write_all(b"something...")?;
child_stdin.write_all(b"something...")?;
```