# What is the Rust equivalent of the system function in C++?

Tags: rust

I tried searching, but found nothing. All I want to do is run system commands/shell commands. The main one though, is `cls`.

**EDIT**:

I did find a question that answers my question really well.
Here's that: [How do I invoke a system command and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-and-capture-its-output)

Comment: `std::process::Command` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I found a question while waiting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-and-capture-its-output which answered my needs. Thanks again :)

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of that question, then?