# How to print all command output?

Tags: rust, output, stdout

How can I print out a command's output?

```
let mut telnet_scan_command = Command::new("telnet");
telnet_scan_command.arg("0.0.0.0");

match telnet_scan_command.output() {
    Ok(o) => {
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8_unchecked(o.stdout))
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Something Went wrong Log: {} ", e)
    }
```

The program runs perfectly fine but the output should be:

```
Trying 0.0.0.0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The actual output is:

```
Trying 0.0.0.0...
```

How can I get the rest of the output?

Comment: Errors are usually printed to `stderr`, so you'd need to get that

Comment: Thank you it worked biut now the telnet command says "Name or service not known" same with ping like it dosen't detect it (sorry i"m kinda new )

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I invoke a system command and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-and-capture-its-output)

Comment: That's a separate issue, so you'd need to ask a new question and provide details about your setup and what you're trying to connect to; however, it's just a problem with connecting with telnet and not related to programming, so not on topic for StackOverflow.