# Source a SQL file from Rust

Tags: mysql, rust

I am pretty new to rust.

I need to source a external SQL file from within rust; here is what I tried, Please refer to the Comment and line break and the error I have mentioned:

```
async fn test_db(
    user_name: &str,
    password: &str,
    database: &str,
    authorization_script_path: &str,
    ) -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
       let connection_string = format!("mysql://{}:{}@localhost:3306", user_name, 
       password);
let connection_url: &str = &connection_string;
let pool = Pool::new(connection_url)?;
let mut connection = pool.get_conn()?;

let create_db_query = format!("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {}", database);
let result_create = connection.query_drop(create_db_query);
println!("{:?}", result_create.unwrap());

let use_db_query = format!("USE {}", database);
let _result_query = connection.query_drop(use_db_query);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// here below I am trying to source a file using the `source` command 
let authoriztion_source_script_query = format!("source {}", &authorization_script_path);
let _result_authorization_script = connection.query_drop(authoriztion_source_script_query);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

   return Ok(());
}
```

I use the follwing the following command to run  my program
`cargo run -- -u root -p super_secret_password -d customera_authorization -A "C:\Users\<some_user_name>\Downloads\<Some_folder>\authorization.sql"`

The `-u` flag is to pass a username for the mysql server.
The `-p` flag is to pass a password for the mysql server.
The `-d` flag is to pass a name of a database to be created
The `-A` flag is to pass a path to the external sql file to be sourced.

when I check for the new database, I found that the DB has been created with the proper name but the SQL file is not sourced

The error I am getting is as follows:
`MySqlError { ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source C:\Users\<some_user_name>\Downloads\<Some_folder>\authorization.sql' at line 1 } Success`

Note: The External SQL file has `CREATE TABLE ....` commands

I just want to source the external SQL file in one go.

Please guide me if possible for fixing this issue

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: which DB library are you using? Are you sure you *don't* have a syntax error in your sql file?

Comment: I am using  `mysql::prelude::*` and `mysql::*`, I am sure I do not have any syntax error in the SQL file as when I try to source it directly from command line it sources without any issues and I am able to see the tables in the DB

Comment: `source` is not SQL, it's an internal command from the [official mysql command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Okay Understood!!, any Idea how can I call this command from rust or any other way to add multiple SQL statements from a file ? keeping in mind that I will be using this script into a Azure VM inside a MySQL subnet

Comment: I can only think of having a pure SQL file (either by preprocessing the file to rewrite it or by changing the code that generates it) or loading the file though the command-line utility (I can't speak Rust, but it'll have shell execution functions for sure).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález could you please provide me with the shell script ? I would try to do a work around

Comment: [How do I invoke a system command and capture its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011330/how-do-i-invoke-a-system-command-and-capture-its-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another solution. sqlx for rust has a [query_file!](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.0/sqlx/macro.query_file.html) macro that directly sources a query from a file. sqlx supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, and MSSQL.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I tried your solution too it works like wonders Thank you again !!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this exists and it's called [include_sql](https://docs.rs/include-sql/latest/include_sql/) - it's a macro that's not used directly but powers other crates into providing seamless integration with queries isolated into separate SQL files. For example there's [include-postgres-sql](https://crates.io/crates/include-postgres-sql), and ones for Oracle and SQLite are available too. There isn't one yet available for MySQL as of this writing.

So if the choice of the database isn't flexible, which I assume it isn't, your best bet appears to be parsing a `.sql` file with the [standard tools](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-02-reading-a-file.html).

Also there's [rawsql](https://github.com/manute/rawsql) that could help, especially if you have a bunch of queries in the same `.sql` file.

Comment: I have used a little different approach to fix this problem, that is by calling msql commands shell / cmd commands from within rust (the pre-requisit being installing the mysqsl client server edition), it does the job! Thank you for your insghts tho :) was helpful!